# What does the little star underneath the vote for a question do?

Tags: support, voting

I was just looking at a question and I clicked the little star underneath the vote and then I realized that I had no idea what it did.

Comment: It looks pretty.

Comment: If you press it, you get 500 rep.

Comment: It's the self-destruct. Don't press it.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Box_(2009_film)

Comment: It's the least understood and least useful feature of SE. Barely ekeing out bounties. and tags. and CW.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

**It marks the question as a favourite.**

If you hover your cursor over the star (assuming you’re using a device that has a cursor to hover), you’ll see the description:

> This is a favourite question (click again to undo)

All this means is that you found the question interesting, and want to follow it. It has no impact on reputation. You can see all your favourited questions on the [/favorites tab](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/users/57258/the-mandolorian?tab=favorites) of your user profile. Many people use favourites as an informal bookmarking system.

There’s [an FAQ on Meta.SE](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/53580/226928) that explains, in detail, how favourites work and what they mean.

Comment: +1 for the U in "favourite".